# Binding a combobox to a database and gridview

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, data-binding, combobox

I am displaying a database table on a grid view and displaying a selected item's details in a detailsview. 
Here's the problem:
There's a combobox in the detailsview and I want to display the added value's string on grid and I want the combobox to select this value. 
It will be possible to update, delete the selected item from grid or add a new item. And I couldn't do the transformations of string- comboboxitem-database item. And I am quite confused on the binding operations. I hope my question is clear enough. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that may preserve your sanity. Only allow edits in your detailsView. Use the grid to Add (clicking an Add Link which shows the detailsView) or Delete. Is it really necessary for the user to be able to edit in either place?